# Circle Slider Hour Android Tester

Tags: android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I want to set my slider hour android in selenium tester.

My code

```
protected void hourCircularSlider(WebElement sliderHour) {
    Actions move = new Actions(getDriverInstance());
    //Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(sliderHour, 10, 0).build();
    //action.perform();
    move.clickAndHold(sliderHour).moveByOffset(10,0).release().perform();
}
```

And the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["actions"]} and you sent ["element"]
os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Comment: This is probably versions mismatch, what are your Selenium and AndroidDriver versions?